# How to align button of RadioButton in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, radio-button

I'm doing a SignUp form to select the gender with a RadioGroup and three RadioButtons. The problem is that I want to center the button but it shows aligned on the left.

[How it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9fNX.png)

**radio group code**:

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


                <RadioButton
                    style="@style/FemaleRadioButton"
                    android:id="@+id/genderFemaleRadioButton"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:button="@drawable/female_radio_btn" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/genderMaleRadioButton"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:button="@drawable/male_radio_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/genderOtherRadioButton"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:button="@drawable/other_radio_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </RadioGroup>
```

I tried to use attributes on XML, also styles to set gravity but it does not work.

Here is the code of **female_radio_btn.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_female_on" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_female_off"/>

</selector>
```

Does someone know if I'm doing it the right way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your radio group:

```
 android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I'll edit with a photo of how it shows